# Why is Google's current nasdaq market cap almost twice the current share price * the No. of shares outstanding?

Tags: stock-markets, market-capitalization, google

Shouldn't the market cap be exactly the current share price * the no. of shares outstanding?

at the time of writing the share price is 537.37 and the no. of shares is 342.63 million, but the market cap is 372.85 billion.  Why is this? Am I doing a computation incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each class A share (GOOGL) there's a class C share (GOOG), hence the missing half in your calculation. The *almost* comes from the slightly higher market price of the class A shares (due to them having voting powers) over class C (which have no voting powers).

There's also class B share which is owned by the founders (Larry, Sergei, Eric and perhaps some to Stanford University and others) and differs from class A by the voting power. These are not publicly traded.

Answer (score 2):

http://mobile.nytimes.com/blogs/economix/2014/04/02/the-many-classes-of-google-stock/

Are you counting both class A and other share classes?

Comment: There's also class B....